# 'serviceBusTrigger', 'signalR' binding types suddenly not registered

Tags: typescript, azure, signalr, azure-functions, azureservicebus

This was working until very recently when it seems to have randomly broken.

Following the guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-register#extension-bundles) I had previously had signalr and servicebus working just fine locally.

It appears that somehow broke without me changing anything I'm aware of, my host.json has no diffs in its history and looks like this:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
  }
}
```

I tried adding service bus to the extensions.json:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <WarningsAsErrors></WarningsAsErrors>
    <DefaultItemExcludes>**</DefaultItemExcludes>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    **<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="3.2.0" />**
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator" Version="1.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

But that caused further errors:

> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type
>   'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.IOptionsFormatter' from assembly
>   'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

Since I hadnt changed anything before it broke I feel like that is not the correct fix, certainly doesn't follow the documentation from Microsoft.

Also tried doing a func extensions install but got the following:

```
No action performed. Extension bundle is configured in {...directory...}
```

Also get this ons tartup:

> Unable to load startup extension 'SignalR' (Type:
>   'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.SignalRService.SignalRWebJobsStartup,
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.SignalRService, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'). The type does not
>   exist. Please validate the type and assembly names.

Also tried deleting AppData/Local/Temp/Functions and got some even scarier errors:

> A host error has occurred during startup operation
>   'fe7c00af-2f47-4972-9060-e3646811d16c'. [20/04/2020 5:07:05 PM]
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus: Could not load type
>   'Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Management.ManagementClient' from assembly
>   'Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.2.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7e34167dcc6d6d8c'. [20/04/2020 5:07:05 PM] Stopping
>   JobHost Value cannot be null. Parameter name: provider

Comment: I think the code you post is not extensions.json. Do you paste the wrong thing? It seems come from C#, not typescript.

Comment: HI, any update?

Comment: It just came with the eazure function for typescript so not sure... maybe it has no affect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

aaaaaaaand I worked it out, turns out after deleting AppData/Local/Temp/Functions the reason for the error was the bin directory in my functions app, after deleting that everything started working great.

Comment: Don't forget to mark your answer, this will help others.:)

Comment: This works, thanks :) Paste this on File Explorer `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Temp\Functions` and delete `ExtensionBundles` folder, for those who want copy and paste.

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same thing happen, but deleting bin didn't work. Instead, I removed the following from host.json

```
"extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
}
```

Then I ran `func extensions install`. Seems to be working now.

Comment: Yep I had to delete the bin folder and AppData/Local/Temp/Functions but your suggestion sounds simpler, hopefully between your answer and mine we can save people a lot of trouble :)